# Address operator with pointer to member function

Tags: c++, class, pointers

We know that to create a "common" pointer to a function we can do for example:

```
void fun();
void (*ptr)() = fun;
```

The name of a function is also the address where the function start. So I do not need to use the address operator & like this:

```
void (*ptr)() = &fun;
```

Now for a pointer to a member function on the contrary I must use the address operator. For example for a class A with a pointer to member function ptr and a function fun() I must write:

```
void(A::*ptr)() = &A::fun;
```

Why this difference?

Comment: The history of allowing use of function names in place of pointers goes back to the early C times - roughly the same time when language designers decided to let array names represent the pointer to their first element. This decision has been inconsistent with the majority of other pointer use cases, when `&` is mandatory. C++ eliminated this problem for things that were not available in C.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is because now that function is defined inside the class. Pointer to member function  holds the "relative address" of where the function is in the class layout and so you have to access it that way.

In case of static, it has no this pointer and it behaves like a global function and so, you can access it like normal function pointer.

Comment: I tried to write it in very simple language and that's why you can say that! But I think I deserve an upvote as the answer is correct :D

Comment: Yes, I read something like that but I have not fully understood. So the member function pointer doesn't point to the function but first to the class of the function and then, indirectly, through an offset, to the function.. Right?

Comment: Yes. It is relative to class as I said

Comment: I was just joking man! Nothing serious. Thanks for the upvote though

Answer (score 2):

According to the C++ standard:

> **4.3 Function-to-pointer conversion** [conv.func]
>
> An lvalue of function type `T` can be converted to a prvalue of type
>   “pointer to `T`”. The result is a pointer to the function.
>
> This conversion never applies to non-static member functions because
>   an lvalue that refers to a non-static member function cannot be
>   obtained.

Answer (score 0):

I think difference is because `A::fun` is non-static member of class `A`. I mean, if your `fun()` is static member of `A` it will be like for ordinary function. Try it.