# Why there is no implicit conversions to pointers of member functions

Tags: c++, c++11

When used `std::bind`, I found `&` is necessary to get the address of member functions, while isn't necessary for regular functions, for example:

```cpp
class Obj{
public:
    void member_func(int val);
};

void func(int val);

int main(){
    Obj obj;
    auto mf1 = std::bind(&Obj::member_func, &obj, 1); // ok
    auto mf2 = std::bind(Obj::member_func, &obj, 1); // error
    
    auto f1 = std::bind(&func, 1); // ok
    auto f2 = std::bind(func, 1); // ok
}
```

And after `STFW`(Search The **Friendly** Web :) ), I found this in [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Function_to_pointer)

> An lvalue of function type T can be implicitly converted to a prvalue pointer to that function. This does not apply to non-static member functions because lvalues that refer to non-static member functions do not exist.

Which explains why `&` is necessary for member functions, but I still don't fully understand why there is no implicit conversions to pointers of member functions?

In particular, what does `"lvalues that refer to non-static member functions do not exist"` mean?

And `"lvalue of function type"` also confuses me, does that mean the function designator `func` is an lvalue?

*First time to ask question, hope I clearly explained my question.*

Comment: That quote is almost literal from the Standard. As to why, I think, this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501982/address-operator-with-pointer-to-member-function#comment62498961_37501982) explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I still don't fully understand why there is no implicit conversions to pointers of member functions.

It's primarily to stop you making mistakes like this:

```
if (MyClass::MyFunc) ...                    // oops! would always be true, if legal
```

when you meant to type:

```
if (MyClass::MyFunc ()) ...
//                  ^^
```

And that's a Good Thing (tm).

But that begs the question, why don't things work the same way for regular functions?  After all, it's perfectly legal (but, as in the example above, totally meaningless) to write:

```
if (MyNonMemberFunc) ...                    // oops! always true, rats!
```

And this is a throwback to C, where function names decay to pointers when you leave the brackets off.  That has value, but overall I think most people would prefer correctness to having to add a leading `&` when that is the intention.

So it's a bit unfortunate that we have different rules for member and non-member functions, but the standards committee obviously wanted to fix this particular booby trap for member functions but couldn't for non-member functions, in order to maintain backwards compatibility.  And to be fair, most modern compilers do warn you if you write `if (MyNonMemberFunc)` so we're not in such a bad place with this, all things considered.

Comment: Your answer is a conjecture. And i don't think it is the real reason. In particular the real reason(as also explained in my answer) is that pointers to member are distinct from the type pointers and moreover except for pointers to static members, text referring to “pointers” does not apply to pointers to members **meaning that they should be treated differently**. Which is why we have to explicitly use `&` for them. That is, to emphasis on the notion that they are distinct types from type pointer.

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way @anoop, but I see a lot of my younger self in you.

Comment: (And just so you know, it wasn't me that downvoted you.)

Comment: I see, i thought you downvoted and then explained the reason for it, below my answer. But that was not the case. I also think that apart from historical reasons(as explained in your answer) there is a factual reason(as explained in my answer) for not allowing implicit conversion in this case. In particular, i think that the quoted statements from the standard in my answer can be logically used to answer the question at hand as done in my answer.

Comment: Good of you to take that in the spirit it was intended. And let's just say the answers are complimentary :)

Comment: Yeah. There may be more than one reason for the existence of a particular thing. Also, i think you had a typo in your last comment because you most probably meant *"complementary"* instead of *"complimentary"* right?

Comment: @anoop Correct.  A Freudian slip, perhaps...

Answer (score 0):

> why there is no implicit conversions to pointers of member functions?

Pointer to **non-static** member functions are not actually pointers. This can be seen from the following statement in the standard:

From [dcl.mptr#3's note](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.mptr#3):

> [ Note: See also [expr.unary] and [expr.mptr.oper]. **The type “pointer to member” is distinct from the type “pointer”**, that is, a pointer to member is declared only by the pointer to member declarator syntax, and never by the pointer declarator syntax. There is no “reference-to-member” type in C++.  — end note ]

And from [basic.compound#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.compound#3):

> ...Except for pointers to static members, **text referring to “pointers” does not apply to pointers to members**...

(emphasis mine)

The combination of the above two quoted statements explain why we need to use `&` for pointer to member function as explained below.

Note the highlight part("distinct type") in the above quoted statement. Since a pointer to member is a distinct type and text referring to pointers does not apply to pointers to members this means that **they should be treated differently**. Which is why we need to explicitly add the `&` for them to emphasize on the fact that they are distinct from the type pointer.

---

Now coming to your second question:

> what does "lvalues that refer to non-static member functions do not exist" mean?

The standard specifically says(in the same [note](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.mptr#3) quoted above) that:

> There is no “reference-to-member” type in C++.

Comment: Repeating the standard without any explanation, especially not regarding the questions of OP... for me it feels that it will not help to answer anything which was asked by OP...

Comment: @Klaus The first line of my answer explains how there is no implicit conversion. In particular, because a) pointer to member functions are not pointers and b) the standard says that *".Except for pointers to static members, text referring to “pointers” does not apply to pointers to members"* and also standard specifically that *"This does not apply to non-static member functions because lvalues that **refer to** non-static member functions do not exist."*. All statement quoted in my answer are related to OP's question.

Comment: "why there is no implicit conversions to pointers of member functions"

Comment: @Klaus Because the standard says so? Are you asking why the standard says so?

Comment: @Klaus The second quoted statement in my answer is there to emphasis on the fact that *"we should not assume that there will be implicit conversions to pointers to member function"* since the standard say: *"text referring to “pointers” does not apply to pointers to members"*.

Comment: _Are you asking why the standard says so?_ Yes he is (obviously).  And so am I.

Comment: @PaulSanders I have added some more information clarifying(if it was not already) why the standard says to use `&` explicitly for pointer to member functions.