# GCC compiles use of noexcept operator but clang and msvc rejects it

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer, noexcept, exception-specification

While writing code involving `noexcept` I made a typo and was surprised to see that the program compiled in gcc but not in clang and msvc. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WvheW6nvW)

```
struct C
{
    void func() noexcept
    {

    }
    void f() noexcept(noexcept(C::func)) //gcc compiles this but clang and msvc rejects this
    {
    }
};
```

So **my question is** which compiler is right here(if any)?

Comment: `&C::func` works for all

Comment: @Quimby Yes, i noticed that.

Comment: Alright, just wanted to add it for context.

Comment: `void f() noexcept(noexcept(C::func()))` works for all of them o_O I think GCC have en extension

Comment: @VictorGubin Yes, `C::func()` is supposed to work but `C::func` not because the latter is ill-formed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is **ill-formed** and *gcc is wrong in accepting the code* because we cannot name a non-static member function in an unevaluated-context like `decltype` or `sizeof` or `noexcept operator`.

This can be seen from [expr.prim.id](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id#general-3):

> An `id-expression` that denotes a non-static data member or `non-static member function of a class can only be used:
>
> - as part of a class member access in which the object expression refers to the member's class or a class derived from that class, or
> - to form a pointer to member ([expr.unary.op]), or
> - if that id-expression denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand.
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
>     struct S {
>      int m;
>    };
>    int i = sizeof(S::m);           // OK
>    int j = sizeof(S::m + 42);      // OK
> ```
>
> — end example
> ]

And since the id-expression `C::func` denotes the non-static member function but does not fall under any of the three listed categories, the program is **ill-formed**.

Here is the gcc bug:

[GCC compiles invalid use of non static member function in noexcept operator](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=107211)

---

Note also that if `C::func` denoted a non-static data member(instead of member function) then the program would've been well-formed because of the third bullet in the above list. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KPM34ha1Y)

Similarly, if you were to write `&C::func` that would also have worked(well-formed) because of the 2nd bullet in the above quoted list.

Comment: It occurs to me that this might vaguely be a subtler version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72166787/why-there-is-no-implicit-conversions-to-pointers-of-member-functions)

Comment: @PaulSanders Replying to your second comment where you linked a similar question. Yes, similar indeed as there is no implicit conversion of `C::func` to pointer to non-static member functions. But here the important thing is that just the use of `C::func` will make the program ill-formed.