# Does using concepts allow using decltype on member function

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts, decltype

I came to [know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74024419) that for a class `X` with a member function named `func`, the c++ standard doesn't allow us to write `decltype(X::func)`. Thus I expected the below given program to produce an error saying something like `invalid use of non-static member function`. But to my surprise, the program [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/Ma67TTs5e) with all 3 compilers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits> 
#include <concepts>

template < typename T >
concept test = std::same_as <decltype(T::func), int(int) >;

struct D
{
    int func(int);
};

int main()
{ 
    std::cout << test<D>;      
}
```

The above program is compiled by all 3 compilers. By looking at [expr.prim.id] it seems the program should be ill-formed and a diagnostic should be emitted. But none of the compilers provide any error. So, does the use of `concept` in a way shown in the program make the program well-formed or is it still ill-formed and are all compilers wrong?

Comment: Looks like all compilers are wrong because `constraint-expression` should be a valid expression(which it is not in this example).

Comment: Substitutions that result in invalid types or expressions inside atomic constraints should result in the constraint not being satisfied (i.e. false). Unless any compiler prints 1, this should compile. I mean... that's SFINAE!

Comment: @StoryTeller : I upvoted your comment, and then immediately realized it's wrong. :-D `std::same_as` is not an atomic constraint, so the rules of normalization apply here instead, and those dictate "If any such substitution results in an invalid type or expression, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic is required." (\[temp.constr.normal\])

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica [SFINAE doesn't mean/guarantee that you won't get any hard errors](https://godbolt.org/z/rjPrGv75v).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Also note [this program doesn't compile](https://godbolt.org/z/W6d5EnvWf). So your previous comment is incorrect.

Comment: I'm well aware of the possibility of hard errors. That doesn't mean there *must* be one here.

Comment: @ildjarn - Interestingly enough, the normative text I found speaks of substitution into the parameter mapping being sfinae friendly. Now, the mapping is formed as part of constraint normalization, so I'm not entirely clear on where the failure is meant to be hard. I mean, does it need to know the concrete types to be normalized?

Comment: @StoryTeller : [temp.constr.normal]/1 gives an explicit example of passing an invalid expression as a concept argument and then summarizes it "*Normalization of `C`'s constraint-expression results in the program being ill-formed, because it would form the invalid type `V&*` in the parameter mapping.*" I can't interpret this as anything other than ill-formed NDR. (Yes, I know the example is non-normative; yet it's there for a reason...)

Comment: @StoryTeller : I think we're talking past each other with these edits. Good question. :-] I'll have to revisit this after some rest, my brain isn't coping well with the standardese right now

Comment: @ildjarn - I hear you. But I feel I should at least point out that `V&*` is ill-formed regardless of what `V` is, whereas `decltype(T::func)` is entirely dependent.

Comment: BTW, @val, your second example where "I'm incorrect" is comparing apples to oranges. Unless told it's a type, C++ assumes objects/values in template code. So there's no need to substitute to know it's wrong (hence the hard error). Specify it's a `typename` you expect, and now we are back to all compilers accepting it https://godbolt.org/z/YG3aKG9WM while printing `0`.

Comment: @StoryTeller : Is this a correct statement? "During normalization, `Y` of `std::same_as<Y, Z>` is mapped to `decltype(D::func)`, which then results in an invalid expression during substitution." If not, what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @ildjarn - I think "substitution" is overloaded here. When we do the mapping, we substitute one concept's parameters into types and expressions of another, and we do so recursively until we reach an atomic constraint where the "top-level" parameters are mapped to some type-or-expression that is formally dependent. Then there's also the substitution of the "top-level" template arguments into the mapping to check if the atomic constraints are satisfied. Either way, I think the standard differentiates poorly between the instance where a mapping can't be made at all (`V&*`) to when it's dependent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does the use of concept in a way shown in the program make the program well-formed

The program is **well-formed** as explained below. From [temp.constr.normal]:

> The normal form of an expression E is a constraint (13.5.2) that is defined as follows:
>
> - The normal form of a concept-id C<A1, A2, ..., An> is the normal form of the constraint-expression
>   of C, after substituting A1, A2, ..., An for C’s respective template parameters in the parameter
>   mappings in each atomic constraint. **If any such substitution results in an invalid type or expression,
>   the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic is required.**

(emphasis mine)

Note the emphasis on the last sentence. In particular, it is about **parameter mapping**. That is, if the parameter mapping results in an invalid type, then only the program will be IFNDR.

But in your given example, the parameter mapping is `T ->decltype(T::func)` which is not in itself an invalid type. Thus, the above quoted reference is not satisfied.

---

Now, from [temp.constr.atomic#3]:

> To determine if an atomic constraint is satisfied, **the parameter mapping and template arguments are first substituted into its expression.
> If substitution results in an invalid type or expression, the constraint is not satisfied.**
> Otherwise, the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is performed if necessary, and E shall be a constant expression of type bool.
> The constraint is satisfied if and only if evaluation of E results in true.
> If, at different points in the program, the satisfaction result is different for identical atomic constraints and template arguments, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

(emphasis mine)

And since the substitution of the template argument `D` results in an invalid construct `decltype(D::func)`, the given constraint is not satisfied(meaning it is `false`).

---

> are all compilers wrong?

Thus, all compilers are correct in accepting the program and outputting `0`.

Answer (score 3):

Substitution failure during satisfaction checking of constraints does not result in the program being ill-formed; it simply causes the constraint to not be satisfied. The relevant text from the standard here is [[temp.constr.atomic]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.atomic#3.sentence-2):

> To determine if an atomic constraint is *satisfied*, the parameter mapping and template arguments are first substituted into its expression. If substitution results in an invalid type or expression, the constraint is not satisfied. Otherwise...

Per [[temp.names]/9](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#9), to determine the value of `test<D>` we first need to reduce `test`'s constraint expression to its [normal form](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.normal). For the sake of convenience, let's assume `same_as<T, U>` is defined as `std::is_same_v<T, U>` (in actuality it's [slightly different](https://eel.is/c++draft/concept.same), but that doesn't affect this answer).

Normalizing the constraint expression of `test` results in an atomic constraint `std::is_same_v<T, U>` with the mapping [`T` -> `decltype(T::func)`, `U` -> `int(int)`]. Note that the parameter mappings denote perfectly valid types (one dependent), so [[temp.constr.normal]/1.4](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.normal#1.4.sentence-2) (the IFNDR case) does not apply.

An invalid expression is only formed when `D` is substituted for (`test`'s) `T`, which according to the text quoted above simply means that `test<D>` is `false`, and the program is well-formed.